# Plotting decision tree in python

Tags: python, plot

I would like to plot the learning curves of decision tree by using the dataset from sklearn in python. And I have tried to script the code to train the learning model.

```
# prepare data
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = iris.data
target = iris.target
# train a decision tree
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(data, target)
# predict from SVM model
print clf.predict([[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2]]) #note that you need to pass a list of    list
print clf.predict([[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2], [4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2]]) #since sometimes you  want to make more than one predictions in one call
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? How does your current output differ from your expected output?

Comment: OK, and what happens when you run it? I'm presuming it doesn't work which is why you're asking, but that would be guesswork :)

Comment: @Tuffwer I am pretty new to python (or programming), and my question might be silly. But how can I plot the learning curve of the model after I train the model?

Comment: There are several ways to draw a plot in python, but which one you would use would depend on exactly what you want to plot and how the data you are plotting is stored.  A quick google search turned up [this page for scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html) Maybe start there?  I don't know enough about sklearn to provide a generic plotting tutorial

Comment: What do you mean by learning curves ? Do you mean ROC curves (Receiver Operating Characteristic curves) ? If you want to do this you will have to split you dataset into a train and test set. You can find an [example on the iris data set on scikit-learn website](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html). If you want, I can build an answer upon this.